# How to point DNS record to IP with port?

Tags: redirect, dns, server, ip

I have a website. `example.com` 
The website is hosted on bluehost
I would like to point a subdomain `pediatri.example.com` to another website hosted on another server (`95.110.189.135:8080`) the problem is that i can't CNAME to an ip with a port.
I tried using an SRV record like that:
[image: SRV record]
I can't change the port to 80 on the other server, and i need the subdomain to point to the ip with the port and everything to work fine. Is there a way to do that? I appreciate every answer and comment. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to do that; DNS maps a domain name to an IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS only works at the IP Address level, its only concern is mapping domain names to IP Addresses, there is no way to specify a port number.

Srv records only work for applications that understand them and are specifically programmed to look them up and configure themselves accordingly.

Comment: So what is the solution?